# Division using bitmanipulation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So I am trying to understand some code which divides y into x (x/y). What I cant understand is why power is initialized to 32. Shouldnt it be 64 because longs in Java are 64 bits long?

```
public static long divide(long x,long y) {
   long result = 0;
   int power = 32;
   long yPower = y << power;
   while (x >= y) {
      while (yPower > x) {
         yPower >>>= 1;
         --power;
      }
      result += 1L << power;
      x -= yPower;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: And then shift left by 64? Clearly not.

Comment: @harold could you explain why power is set to 32 then?

Comment: I guess this code is really meant to divide 32bit numbers, it doesn't even work at all with arbitrary 64bit `y` and it works unacceptably slowly for some 64bit `x`. Is there more context that would agree with that? On what sort of inputs is this function actually called? (or is it just some snippet?)

Comment: @harold, I ran the code on intellij with two long inputs and it worked fine, the correct answer was returned

Comment: Yes well try to divide by `1L << 32` for example, doesn't end well.

Comment: It uses `long` because `1 << 32` doesn't fit into an `int`. But its domain is still `int`. You can't use 64.

Comment: @EJP could you explain why I cant use 64?

Comment: Because `1 << 64` doesn't fit into a `long`, as @harold stated above, just as `1 << 32` doesn't fit into an `int`.

Comment: how bout 63? would that work?

Comment: Certainly it would.

Comment: Though it would only allow you to divide by 1, and only after modifying the code a bit, so that's not much help.. That left shift has the same role as the "align left-most digits" in grade school division, but without bothering to align them immediately (doesn't matter, it will shift right until aligned). If that left shift "loses" any bits by pushing them over the left-edge of the number, you are no longer dividing by your original divisor, but only by the lower bits of the divisor.